# SQL Update field remove characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I used this SQL statement to update a table ... and now I need to revert the change. The statement below added 000 to the end of the u_id now i need to remove the 000 that was added

```
UPDATE downloadable_link
SET    u_id = CONCAT(u_id, '000')
WHERE  product_sku = 'test-add'
```

Comment: `set u_id = replace('000','')` ?

Comment: @Stu this will replace the added 000 on the end correct? u_id = 2323000 only the 000 will be removed?

Comment: `UPDATE downloadable_link SET u_id = LEFT(u_id, LENGTH(u_id)-3) WHERE product_sku = 'test-add' AND RIGHT(u_id,3)="000"`.     This should work with an u_id that currently has the value `000123000` too.

Comment: @acctman ideally some sample data would be nice. We have no idea what `u_id` actually contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
UPDATE downloadable_link
SET    u_id = TRIM(TRAILING '000' FROM u_id)
WHERE  product_sku = 'test-add';
```

This is safer because it removes '000' only from the end. Just in case there are some u_id values with '000' in the middle.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim for details on the TRIM() function.

If you want to test how the solution will handle different values, then test some queries by running them in the MySQL client:

```
mysql> select trim(trailing '000' from 'a000bc000') as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| a000bc |
+--------+
```